# How to split links generated into an xml sitemap to avoid exceeding 30 sec maximum execution time?

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, mysql, xml

So I am trying to push these kind of URLs into a sitemap `www.example.com/used-cars/location/new-york/model/audi` & `www.example.com/used-cars/model/bmw`

This code seems to do exactly that:

`
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_index', 'add_sitemap_custom_items' );
function add_sitemap_custom_items(){

```
$models = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'vehicle_model',
    'hide_empty' => true,
) );
$locations = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'vehicle_location',
    'hide_empty' => true,
) );

// Loop through the search terms
$pages = '';

foreach ( $models as $model ) {
    $location2 = home_url( '/used-cars/model/' . $model->slug );
    $pages .= "<sitemap><loc>$location2</loc><lastmod>2017-04-04T23:59:00+00:00</lastmod><changefreq>weekly</changefreq><priority>0.8</priority></sitemap>\n";
    foreach ( $locations as $location ) {
        $location2 = home_url( '/used-cars/location/' . $location->slug . '/model/' . $model->slug );
        $pages .= "<sitemap><loc>$location2</loc><lastmod>2017-04-04T23:59:00+00:00</lastmod><changefreq>weekly</changefreq><priority>0.8</priority></sitemap>\n";
    }
```

}
   return $pages;
}

`

But now the problem is that, I get a fatal error of `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\autocity\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 284
Call Stack` , So my guess is that I need to split these links into multiple sitemap files, with each file not having more than 30k links. How do I do that?

Oh and the code generates 84k links. I would like to split these into atleast 20k per sitemap file.